# Split in different columns the content of a cell

Tags: python

I have a column with 1,5k lines and each line has this structure:

```
" [{'id': 4099, 'name': 'xxxxxxxx + 30 filter', 'product_id': 6546, 'variation_id': 3352, 'quantity': 1, 'tax_class': '', 'subtotal': '110.89', 'subtotal_tax': '0.00', 'total': '29.90', 'total_tax': '0.00', 'taxes': [], 'meta_data': [{'id': 39083, 'key': 'pa_size', 'value': 'l', 'display_key': 'Size', 'display_value': 'L'}, {'id': 39094, 'key': '_reduced_stock', 'value': '1', 'display_key': '_reduced_stock', 'display_value': '1'}], 'sku': 'FS00055.L', 'price': 29.9, 'parent_name': 'xxxxxxxx + 30 filter'}] "
```

I want to get to a result in which the keys of the inner dictionary become new columns and the values are copied underneath. For example:

```
id       name                 ......
4099     xxxxxxxx + 30 filter ......
```

I've tried:

```
        import ast
# Acess only the first line and try to split each into columns
li_column = my_df.loc[0,'line_items']
li_column = ast.literal_eval(li_column)
```

Then I was able to get into a list with 1 item that has a dictionary inside, now I'm stuck.

Comment: how did you get this data? It looks like JSON and you could use `json.loads()` to convert string to dictionary. And later you can try to use `pd.Series` with `.apply()` to convert dictionaries to columns. And this problem was few times in some question on SO

Answer (score 0):

I can't convert your string with `ast` but you could use `.apply()` to do it for all rows

```
df['line_items'] = df['line_items'].apply(dirtyjson.loads)
```

Later you could get dictionary from list

```
df['line_items'] = df['line_items'].str[0]
```

And later you can use again `.apply()` with `pd.Series` to create new `DataFrame` from dictionaries.

```
new_df = df['line_items'].apply(pd.Series)
```

---

As I said `ast` doesn't work for me with your strings. Standard `json` has also problem to convert it. But module `dirtyjson` convert it correctly.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'line_items': [
        " [{'id': 4099, 'name': 'xxxxxxxx + 30 filter', 'product_id': 6546, 'variation_id': 3352, 'quantity': 1, 'tax_class': '', 'subtotal': '110.89', 'subtotal_tax': '0.00', 'total': '29.90', 'total_tax': '0.00', 'taxes': [], 'meta_data': [{'id': 39083, 'key': 'pa_size', 'value': 'l', 'display_key': 'Size', 'display_value': 'L'}, {'id': 39094, 'key': '_reduced_stock', 'value': '1', 'display_key': '_reduced_stock', 'display_value': '1'}], 'sku': 'FS00055.L', 'price': 29.9, 'parent_name': 'xxxxxxxx + 30 filter'}] ",
        " [{'id': 4199, 'name': 'xxxxxxxx + 30 filter', 'product_id': 6546, 'variation_id': 3352, 'quantity': 1, 'tax_class': '', 'subtotal': '110.89', 'subtotal_tax': '0.00', 'total': '29.90', 'total_tax': '0.00', 'taxes': [], 'meta_data': [{'id': 39083, 'key': 'pa_size', 'value': 'l', 'display_key': 'Size', 'display_value': 'L'}, {'id': 39094, 'key': '_reduced_stock', 'value': '1', 'display_key': '_reduced_stock', 'display_value': '1'}], 'sku': 'FS00055.L', 'price': 29.9, 'parent_name': 'xxxxxxxx + 30 filter'}] ",
    ]
})

#import ast
#df['line_items'] = df['line_items'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

import dirtyjson
df['line_items'] = df['line_items'].apply(dirtyjson.loads)

df['line_items'] = df['line_items'].str[0]

new_df = df['line_items'].apply(pd.Series)

print(new_df)
```

Result:

```
     id                  name  ...  price           parent_name
0  4099  xxxxxxxx + 30 filter  ...   29.9  xxxxxxxx + 30 filter
1  4199  xxxxxxxx + 30 filter  ...   29.9  xxxxxxxx + 30 filter

[2 rows x 15 columns]
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you need to add it to existing `dataframe`

```
df = df.join(new_df)

# remove old column
del df['line_items']

print(df)
```

---

**EDIT:**

If every list may have more dictionaries then you can use `explode()` instead of `str[0]` - and it will put every dictionary in separated row.

```
df = df.explode('line_items').reset_index(drop=True)  # extract from list
```

---

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    #'A': ['123', '456', '789'],
    'line_items': [
        """ [{'id': 4099, 'name': 'xxxxxxxx + 30 filter', 'product_id': 6546, 'variation_id': 3352, 'quantity': 1, 'tax_class': '', 'subtotal': '110.89', 'subtotal_tax': '0.00', 'total': '29.90', 'total_tax': '0.00', 'taxes': [], 'meta_data': [{'id': 39083, 'key': 'pa_size', 'value': 'l', 'display_key': 'Size', 'display_value': 'L'}, {'id': 39094, 'key': '_reduced_stock', 'value': '1', 'display_key': '_reduced_stock', 'display_value': '1'}], 'sku': 'FS00055.L', 'price': 29.9, 'parent_name': 'xxxxxxxx + 30 filter'},
             {'id': 5099, 'name': 'xxxxxxxx + 30 filter', 'product_id': 6546, 'variation_id': 3352, 'quantity': 1, 'tax_class': '', 'subtotal': '110.89', 'subtotal_tax': '0.00', 'total': '29.90', 'total_tax': '0.00', 'taxes': [], 'meta_data': [{'id': 39083, 'key': 'pa_size', 'value': 'l', 'display_key': 'Size', 'display_value': 'L'}, {'id': 39094, 'key': '_reduced_stock', 'value': '1', 'display_key': '_reduced_stock', 'display_value': '1'}], 'sku': 'FS00055.L', 'price': 29.9, 'parent_name': 'xxxxxxxx + 30 filter'}] """,
        """ [{'id': 4100, 'name': 'xxxxxxxx + 30 filter', 'product_id': 6546, 'variation_id': 3352, 'quantity': 1, 'tax_class': '', 'subtotal': '110.89', 'subtotal_tax': '0.00', 'total': '29.90', 'total_tax': '0.00', 'taxes': [], 'meta_data': [{'id': 39083, 'key': 'pa_size', 'value': 'l', 'display_key': 'Size', 'display_value': 'L'}, {'id': 39094, 'key': '_reduced_stock', 'value': '1', 'display_key': '_reduced_stock', 'display_value': '1'}], 'sku': 'FS00055.L', 'price': 29.9, 'parent_name': 'xxxxxxxx + 30 filter'},
             {'id': 5100, 'name': 'xxxxxxxx + 30 filter', 'product_id': 6546, 'variation_id': 3352, 'quantity': 1, 'tax_class': '', 'subtotal': '110.89', 'subtotal_tax': '0.00', 'total': '29.90', 'total_tax': '0.00', 'taxes': [], 'meta_data': [{'id': 39083, 'key': 'pa_size', 'value': 'l', 'display_key': 'Size', 'display_value': 'L'}, {'id': 39094, 'key': '_reduced_stock', 'value': '1', 'display_key': '_reduced_stock', 'display_value': '1'}], 'sku': 'FS00055.L', 'price': 29.9, 'parent_name': 'xxxxxxxx + 30 filter'}] """,
        """ [{'id': 4101, 'name': 'xxxxxxxx + 30 filter', 'product_id': 6546, 'variation_id': 3352, 'quantity': 1, 'tax_class': '', 'subtotal': '110.89', 'subtotal_tax': '0.00', 'total': '29.90', 'total_tax': '0.00', 'taxes': [], 'meta_data': [{'id': 39083, 'key': 'pa_size', 'value': 'l', 'display_key': 'Size', 'display_value': 'L'}, {'id': 39094, 'key': '_reduced_stock', 'value': '1', 'display_key': '_reduced_stock', 'display_value': '1'}], 'sku': 'FS00055.L', 'price': 29.9, 'parent_name': 'xxxxxxxx + 30 filter'},
             {'id': 5101, 'name': 'xxxxxxxx + 30 filter', 'product_id': 6546, 'variation_id': 3352, 'quantity': 1, 'tax_class': '', 'subtotal': '110.89', 'subtotal_tax': '0.00', 'total': '29.90', 'total_tax': '0.00', 'taxes': [], 'meta_data': [{'id': 39083, 'key': 'pa_size', 'value': 'l', 'display_key': 'Size', 'display_value': 'L'}, {'id': 39094, 'key': '_reduced_stock', 'value': '1', 'display_key': '_reduced_stock', 'display_value': '1'}], 'sku': 'FS00055.L', 'price': 29.9, 'parent_name': 'xxxxxxxx + 30 filter'}] """,
    ]
})

import dirtyjson

df['line_items'] = df['line_items'].apply(dirtyjson.loads)

#df['line_items'] = df['line_items'].str[0]           # extract first item from list
df = df.explode('line_items').reset_index(drop=True)  # extract all items  from list

new_df = df['line_items'].apply(pd.Series)
print(new_df)

df = df.join(new_df)
del df['line_items']

print(df)
```

```
     id                  name  ...  price           parent_name
0  4099  xxxxxxxx + 30 filter  ...   29.9  xxxxxxxx + 30 filter
1  5099  xxxxxxxx + 30 filter  ...   29.9  xxxxxxxx + 30 filter
2  4100  xxxxxxxx + 30 filter  ...   29.9  xxxxxxxx + 30 filter
3  5100  xxxxxxxx + 30 filter  ...   29.9  xxxxxxxx + 30 filter
4  4101  xxxxxxxx + 30 filter  ...   29.9  xxxxxxxx + 30 filter
5  5101  xxxxxxxx + 30 filter  ...   29.9  xxxxxxxx + 30 filter

[6 rows x 15 columns]
```